# Template must be a string error in Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular9, angular-ivy

I'm trying to realize dynamic template in Angular 9 app, based on this example 
[https://plnkr.co/edit/yftZxS45CQpwi3uIM4BV?preview][1]

In Angular 7 it works fine, but in 9 it give errors:

```
ERROR in src/app/html-outlet.ts:32:19 - error NG1010: template must be a string

32         template: html
                     ~~~~
src/app/html-outlet.ts:38:24 - error NG6001: The class 'DynamicHtmlComponent' is listed in the declarations of 
the NgModule 'DynamicHtmlModule', but is not a directive, a component, or a pipe. Either remove it from the 
NgModule's declarations, or add an appropriate Angular decorator.

38         declarations: [DynamicHtmlComponent]
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/html-outlet.ts:34:13
    34       class DynamicHtmlComponent  {};
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'DynamicHtmlComponent' is declared here.
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HtmlOutlet } from './html-outlet';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent, HtmlOutlet
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'htmloutlet';
  html = "Test dynamic component {{ 1 + 1 }}";
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div>
  <h2>Hello</h2>
  <html-outlet [html]="html"></html-outlet>
</div>
```

html-outlet

```
import {
    NgModule,
    Component,
    Directive,
    Input,
    ComponentRef,
    Compiler,
    ViewContainerRef
  } from '@angular/core';

  import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

  @Directive({ selector: 'html-outlet' })
  export class HtmlOutlet {
    @Input() html: string;
    cmpRef: ComponentRef<any>;

    constructor(private vcRef: ViewContainerRef, private compiler: Compiler) { }

    ngOnChanges() {
      const html = this.html;
      if (!html) return;

      if(this.cmpRef) {
        this.cmpRef.destroy();
      }

      @Component({
        selector: 'dynamic-comp',
        template: html
      })
      class DynamicHtmlComponent  {};

       @NgModule({
        imports: [CommonModule ],
        declarations: [DynamicHtmlComponent]
      })
      class DynamicHtmlModule {}

      this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(DynamicHtmlModule)
        .then(factory => {
          const moduleRef = factory.ngModuleFactory.create(this.vcRef.parentInjector);

          const compFactory = factory.componentFactories.find(x => x.componentType === DynamicHtmlComponent);
          const cmpRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(compFactory, 0, moduleRef.injector);
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
      if(this.cmpRef) {
        this.cmpRef.destroy();
      }    
    }
  }
```

my Angular version

```
Angular CLI: 9.1.1
Node: 10.15.3
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 9.1.1
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.901.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.901.1
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.901.1
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.901.1
@angular-devkit/core              9.1.1
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.1.1
@ngtools/webpack                  9.1.1
@schematics/angular               9.1.1
@schematics/update                0.901.1
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.8.3
webpack                           4.42.0
```

The discussion about problem like this:
(https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35584)

Please, tell me, how i can avoid this problem?

Comment: That's due to changes made on how angular builds it code. Keep in mind that decorators (@Component() and so) are compiled, not runtime. So when compiler try to compile it faces with a variable `html` that doesn't exists at compile time.

Comment: @EliasSoares is right. Ivy works only with AOT and that's why you're having trouble. If you disable Ivy, your code still works as long as you do not use AOT. I've put together this [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcomq612192766433166?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) so you can mess around with. But I'm not sure if what you want is impossible to do (create a component out of a string). Maybe there's another approach to do that. If you intend just to work with the template, wouldn't `ng-template` do the job for you?

Comment: @julianobrasil thanks for useful answer! that stackblitz demo works, but only local, it will not work in prod mode (as i understand AOT need to build prod version and it's work). What i want to do - is download from DB server templates of HTML page, with <components> in it. How do u think, will the solution with ng-template work for my task? I found good example, and it seems that it what i need: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-content-viewer?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: I think that might help for those who come across the same problem 1. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15275 2. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-minimal-3

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue, you can try the --aot=false option, for debugging:

> ng serve --aot=false

and for production:

> ng b --prod --aot=false --build-optimizer=false

I've just tested in Angular 10.0.2